# Step selection for migration from magento1 to magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2-migration-tool, data

How to perform magento 1 to magento 2 migration step by step. Like first I want to migrate eav attributes only, Then products and so on.. But one at a time.

So, How should I configure the etc/ce-to-ce//config.xml in the data migration tool to achieve the same. If there is a need to modify other files as well please suggest.